# Magento2 Client Side Less Compilation

Tags: php, magento

при переключении на `Client Side Less Compilation` сайт упал.

> Страница недоступна Сайт site.ru пока не может обработать этот запрос.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

Как вернуть назад? Есть sftp и ssh